# will html input value always be string?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am writing a function which checks the input value.

```
const [input, setInput] = useState("")

<input type="text" value={input} onBlur={handleCheckValue} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
```

And the problem is I don't know how to write check function.
I want a valid string with represent a number like "12345" "489796" ...etc

```
  const handleCheckValue = () => {
    setIsValid(false);
    if (input === undefined || input === null || input.trim() === "" || isNaN(input)){
      setWarnText(warnTextMap["notValid"]);
    } else {
      setIsValid(true);
    }
  };
```

Should I check if it is undefined or null?
I googled and searched but can't find an question like this..

Answer (score 2):

By specification  value is always a string. Check the reference guide with types and details for all properties of the input elements: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

```
value   text    Specifies the value of an <input> element
```

If you want to understand if the value is a valid number you should use:
`!isNaN(parseInt(value))`. This is going to tell you `true` in cases where the string is a valid number and `false` in all other cases.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to have only numbers in your input.

In this case you can change your input type to be number:

```
<input type="number" value={input} onBlur={handleCheckValue} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
```

Comment: `type="number"` also returns `value` in string form

Comment: The Number() method converts a string to a number.